# Gradle dependecies are failed to resolve

Tags: android, build.gradle

I'm using Android Studio version 2.3.3. It has been updated recently. Whenever I try to add a new dependency for any use e.g. recyclerview, cardview, retrofit, etc, the gradle fails to resolve them.
I have mentioned the repositories in gradle file. But there is no solution. 
this is my gradle file

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
   buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.apurva.bargraph"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
       'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
     }
   }

 allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
   maven {url "https://maven.google.com"}
  }
 }

 dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.github.philjay:mpandroidchart:v3.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

 }
```

for each of the dependency, gradle sync fails and I don't know what else to do.
Any kind of help would be great.

Comment: In android when the gradle fails it gives you the some solution too, just goto the logs click on the option ma be it was giving you error like dependencies and all not matched download and retry. Just click on it and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

There may be number of problems for this 
1. First check your **buildToolVersion** which you are using is installed in your sdk.
2. You have to add below code in project gradle file not in app gradle.

```
   maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
   maven {url "https://maven.google.com"}
```

3. Just change the **buildToolVersion**  to higher version which is installed in you studio.

It's May be help you out.

Comment: It was behaving the same way for version 26.0.2

Answer (score 0):

This is because you didn't have support library 25.3.1 installed in your system. So, you need to install the sdk from Android Studio via `Tools->Android->SDK Manager` for support library **below 25.4.0**. You only need to use google maven to use support library [starting from revision 25.4.0](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#25-4-0).

Comment: I have it installed. And previously I was using 26.0.2 and same kind of error occurred  i.e why I step down to this version. But it's also not working

Comment: I've tested your app `build.gradle` as it is, no error found.  Have you check your root `build.gradle`? As the last resort, try `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...`

Comment: I'm done using the invalidate cache method . don't know what's wrong